# Simple alertify confirm not working

Tags: javascript, alertify

I'm implementing a simple alertify confirm that's inside a regular JS function.  I'm using the onclick attribute in my HTML to call this function, which should then execute the alertify code, but nothing happens when I click the button.  Also, all of the documentation I found for alertify completely excludes HTML.  So maybe I am not implementing it correctly in the HTML?  Also, nothing is appearing in Chrome's JS debugger.  So, I am referencing the library correctly at the very least.

**HTML**

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="confirmButton()">Rebuild</button>
```

**JS**

```
function confirmButton() {

    alertify.confirm("Are you sure?",
          function(){
            alertify.success('Yes');
          },
          function(){
            alertify.error('No');
          });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to, you can fix it by doing this:

```
confirmButton = function() {
    alertify.confirm("Are you sure?",
          function(e){
                if(e){
                    alertify.success('Yes');
                } else {
                    alertify.success('No');
                }
          });
}
```

The problem stems from the function not being available to the caller. The fix works by making the function available globally. However, inline JS is pretty bad practice in general and I'd suggest **not** using this. Event handlers are a much better practice, [jQuery's click handler](https://api.jquery.com/click/) would work pretty well here:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
      $('button.btn-primary').click(function(){
           alertify.confirm("Are you sure?",
                function(e){
                if(e){
                    alertify.success('Yes');
                } else {
                    alertify.success('No');
                }
          });
      });
 });
```

Comment: So no other HTML is needed besides the class name?

Comment: If you have many buttons with the same class, then this wouldn't work. You would want to assign an `id` to the "Rebuild" button and then have `$('#yourId').click()` instead.

Comment: Damn that's frustrating.  I'm generating multiple Rebuild buttons with Angular.  I know how to generate unique `ids` dynamically, but may have trouble implementing alertify.  I'll test it in a separate environment to see if it works with one button first...

Comment: Because I hadn't referenced two of the other stylesheets.  My project has so many stylesheets ;(

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your method like so:

```
alertify.confirm("Are you sure?", function (e) {
  if (e) {
    alertify.success("Yes");
  } else {
    alertify.success("No");
  }
});
```